# Clojurescript using nodejs to read stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js, clojurescript

I am unable to read stdin from NodeJs using ClojureScript. Ideally the final commands would be `java -cp cljs.jar:src clojure.main node.clj` followed by `node main.js`. The Javascript version works fine but i'm unable to get it to work using ClojureScript.

#### Clojurescript

```
(ns hello-world.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as string] [cljs.nodejs :as nodejs]))

(nodejs/enable-util-print!)

(defn -main [& args]
  (let [readline (js/require "readline")
    rl (.createInterface readline js/process.stdin js/process.stdout)]
    (.on rl "line" 
     (fn [line]
          (def lineVector (clojure.string/split line #" "))
          (if  (and (nil? lineVector)
                    (< (get lineVector 0) 10) 
                    (< (get lineVector 1) 10))
            (+ (get lineVector 0) (get lineVector 0)))))))

(set! *main-cli-fn* -main)
```

#### Javascript

```
var readline = require('readline');

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  terminal: false
});  

rl.on('line', readLine);

function readLine (line) {...}
```

I get the following error message:

TypeError: a.ac is not a function
    at Function.be.w (/Users/tinatuh/Workspace/AlgorithmicToolbox-Coursera/main.js:212:47)
    at be (/Users/tinatuh/Workspace/AlgorithmicToolbox-Coursera/main.js:211:409)
    at Gc (/Users/tinatuh/Workspace/AlgorithmicToolbox-Coursera/main.js:99:59)
    at Jc (/Users/tinatuh/Workspace/AlgorithmicToolbox-Coursera/main.js:108:60)
    at Object. (/Users/tinatuh/Workspace/AlgorithmicToolbox-Coursera/main.js:212:506)
    at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you are using advanced optimisations in [ClojureScript/Closure compilation](https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#optimizations) which [aggressively renames functions and variables to make the output JavaScript code smaller](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels#advanced_optimizations).

You might try to use simple (`:simple`) optimisations instead or provide externs definitions that will help Closure compiler to correctly process your and libraries code (referenced web page includes a link to [a sample project using externs](https://github.com/dcodeIO/node.js-closure-compiler-externs)).

There is also another issue in your code in how you call `readline.createInterface`: it expects the options object and you are passing it bare options values instead. You need to call it like below:

```
(.createInterface readline
                  #js {:input js/process.stdin
                       :output js/process.stdout})
```

Comment: Externs was the main issue for stdin. @piotrek-bzdyl recommendation of using simple enabled me to read input.